# What does Enumerable.Where in C# do?

Tags: c#

Can someone help me understand the C# code examples below

```
  var selected = APIData.Accounts.Where(x => x["Billing Day A"].ToString() == bA &&  x["Billing Day B"].ToString() == bB);
  var selected = AllowedProducts.ProductA.Where(x => x.Item1 == intType || x.Item1 == DataPrep.InterestType.NONE.ToString()).ToList();
```

I want to know when x => x can be used and what is this trying to achieve in above two scenarios

Comment: [Lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) and  [Enumerable.Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `x => x` (pronounced x goes to x) where x is just a dummy name that stands for one item in the enumeration. The first one must allow an indexed access `[]`, the second one must have a field `item1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Where clause works by iterating through the items in the object that it is call on.

The part that probably makes this confusion is the conditional. Both statements are similar, so I will look at the first one.

```
var selected = APIData.Accounts.Where(x => x["Billing Day A"].ToString() == bA &&  x["Billing Day B"].ToString() == bB);
```

This is similar to a loop that would look like the following:

```
foreach(var x in APIData.Accounts)
{
   if (x["Billing Day A"].ToString() == bA &&  x["Billing Day B"].ToString() == bB)
   {
       // return this item
   }
}
```

This isn't exactly what is happening, but it is just to demonstrate the effect that a Where clause has. More correctly, the Where clause is returning all of the elements from the set (in this case, `APIData.Accounts`) in the form of an IEnumerable.

The `x` variable is the item from `APIData.Accounts` that is accessed as the original set is iterated through.

Comment: Thanks so much @Ryan S